# Make vertical reordering of cells in grid system work responsively

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've got this layout:

```
+--X---------------+--Y---+
|                  |  A   |
|                  + ---- +
|                  |  B   |
+------------------+------+
```

with `X = #main-col` and `Y = #plugin-col` and `A` and `B` being `.plugin`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" id="main-col">…</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="plugin-col">
    <div class="plugin">A</div>
    <div class="plugin">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm using this JavaScript:

```
$('#main-col').toggleClass('col-md-9 col-md-12');
$('#plugin-col').toggleClass('col-md-3 col-md-12 row');
$('#plugin-col .plugin').toggleClass('col-md-3');
```

to achieve this layout:

```
+--X----------------------+
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+------+------+-----------+
|  A   |  B   |
+------+------+
```

Is there a way to achieve the horizontal <-> vertical reordering of the A & B cells automatically and responsively when the browser window shrinks between a certain width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for JS just add one more `row` and use bootstrap col's to get desired result like this. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/594/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" id="main-col">…</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="plugin-col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="plugin col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-6">A</div>
      <div class="plugin col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-6">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```